# How to scp first 100 folders (alphabetically)

Tags: bash, ssh, scp

I'm trying to copy the first 100 directories from a remote server to my machine.  The way I'm currently attempting to do this is:

```
dir="/path/to/files/"
server="user@server.com"
scp -r $server:"$(ssh $server "ls -d ${dir}/* | head -n 100")" .
```

frustratingly, this works for the first directory, and then just spits out an error message for the next 99, which reads (for example):

> bash: line 1: /path/to/files/2nd_directory: is a directory

Does anyone have any thoughts on why this might be happening, and how to avoid it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your expression expands to

```
scp -r server:first second third .
```

so you end up copying `server:first` and local files `second` and `third` to the current directory.

You might want something like

```
scp -r $(ssh $server "ls -d $dir/*" | sed -n -e "s%^%$server:/%p" -e 100q) .
```

This still has the obvious problem of [parsing `ls` output](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) but for a quick fix, if all your directory names are regular, it should work.

Comment: this ends up trying to scp the directory: /path/to/files///path/to/files/2nd_directory

editing it to:
`scp -r $(ssh $server "ls -d $dir/*" | sed -n -e "1,100s%^%$server:/%p" -e 101q) .`
seems to work, but requires I enter my password for every single directory (which is clearly not ideal for 100 directories)

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  The fix for the password is to set up passwordless `ssh`.  Some `scp` implementations are less greedy when you have multiple connections to the same host but the proper fix is public-key authentication anyway.

Comment: thanks, I'll look into it.  the ls still needs to be changed to `ls -d $dir/*` though, as otherwise it's just trying to copy $dir, not the first 100 folders in $dir

Comment: out of curiosity - how would you modify the sed command for the *last* 100 directories?  I'm fairly new to sed..

Comment: Hard with `sed`, easy with `tail`.  Or just use `ls -rd` to reverse the listing.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this `scp+ssh` command:

```
scp -r "$server":"$(ssh "$server" 'cd /path/to/files; a=(*/); \
for ((i=0; i<100 && i<${#arr[@]}; i++)); do printf "/path/to/files/%s " "${a[$i]}"; done')" .
```

This worked for me **without entering password 100 times** since it copies all files in a single `scp` connection.

Comment: So does mine.  I suspect his `scp` is overtly eager to reauthenticate.

Answer (score 1):

```
readarray -t dirs < <(exec ssh "$server" "bash -c \"printf '$server:%s\n' '$dir'/*\"")
scp -r "${dirs[@]:0:100}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider using sftp instead of scp:

```
ssh $server "ls -d ${dir}/* | head -n 100" | sed 's/^/get /' | sftp $server:
```